# Building different images for each environment with Gitlab-CI AutoDevOps

Tags: next.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-autodevops

Dockerfiles accept ENV variables via `--build-args`. These vars are mandatory for NextJS, used for static pages (to call remote APIs) and are "Hard coded" within the built image.

Gitlab-CI AutoDevOps has an ENV var to pass these args (`AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS`). But this is only consumeable if you are using one environment/image. When multiple environments (`staging` and `production`) needed, the URLs differ (`https://staging.exmpl.com` and `https://www.exmpl.com`).

How do I have to modify the Gitlab AutoDevOps to have two different images built?

In the CI/CD Settings my `AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS` are set:

```
--build-arg=API_URL=https://staging.exmpl.at/backend --build-arg=NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://staging.exmpl.at/backend
# as well $NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL is set there
```

Currently this is my complete `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

# added vars for build
build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    API_URL: $NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: $NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
```

How can I build two images, without "leaving" AutoDevOps? I assume I have to customize the build stage.

**Another idea** is to create a second Git repository called **production** with production URL set for `$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL`:

- Staging get build and runs tests.
- if successful it gets published
- Staging repo content will be copied to the production repo
- Production repo gets build (with production URL) and tested and then published too

Then I have two images.

**Has someone please a better idea?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a couple way you can do this. It's pretty easy if you only care about the build job.

One way would be to make a second job which `extends:` from `build`

```yaml
build:
  variables:
    MY_ENV: staging

build production:
  extends: build
  variables:
    MY_ENV: production
```

Another way might be to add a `parallel:matrix:` key to the `build` job

```yaml
build:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - MY_ENV: staging
      - MY_ENV: production
```

Keep in mind, however, if any jobs downstream of `build` depends on its artifacts, you'll need to manage those as well.

For example:

```yaml
build:
  variables:
    MY_ENV: staging

build production:
  extends: build
  variables:
    MY_ENV: production

# some other job inherited from a template that depends on `build`
# we also want two of these jobs for each environment
downstream:
  variables:
    MY_ENV: staging

# extend it for production
downstream production:
  extends: downstream
  dependencies:  # make sure we get artifacts from correct upstream build job
    - build production
  variables:
    MY_ENV: production
```

Comment: Thank you @sytech. your first example worked, I only had to add additional `build_artifact`, as well the `script:` because without them, the second build was overwriting the first one as well the first `build_artifact`. So I copied the `script:` part from DevOps original build file and added a suffix to the build name, to differentiate between these two builds

Comment: @Jan glag that worked. Another way to deal with downstream build artifacts is to extend the downstream job and add an explicit `dependencies:` key pointing to the correct upstream job(s). Then the downstream job(s) will only receive artifacts from the respective upstream job(s) you define in `dependencies:`. I'll add this to my answer. However, that may not be easy with `parallel:matrix:`.